# Как правильно сделать секундную паузу в цикле?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Как лучше поступить: так - `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` или так - `Thread.sleep(1000);`  ? Дело в том, что если сделать `Thread.sleep(1000);` за циклом (задача выполняется в AsyncTask) то он почему то ещё затрагивает другой класс Thread в этом же классе! Не произойдёт ли такого в цикле?

```
private class ReadThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
        //  . . .
        }
    }

public class readT extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {    

    protected String doInBackground(String... mode) { 

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

              try {

Thread.sleep(1000); // <-- Здесь он ставит на паузу класс ReadThread 

                while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 30000) {

Thread.sleep(1000); // <-- А здесь (вроде) не ставит и работает только для цикла?               
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }   

return null;  

    }  

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   


         }

       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разницы нет. Непонятно что кто где там затрагивает в том же классе.
Если посмотреть исходники, то можно увидеть, что `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)` внутри вызывает `Thread.sleep(1000);`

Comment: В том же классе что и ассинхрон с циклом находиться ещё класс private class ReadThread extends Thread { ... }, так вот, если делать паузу Thread.sleep(1000); за циклом, он почему то ещё заодно останавливает задачу в вышеупомянутом классе.

Comment: @Incognito, смотря где выполняется Thread.sleep(1000);    
Покажите ваш код. Не понятно все равно

Comment: Вставил код, гляньте пожалуйста!

Comment: @Incognito, я не вижу причин ему ставить на паузу выполнение кода в ReadThread. Тем более, что он якобы не делает этого в цикле. Это вообще не имеет смысла.

Comment: Теперь всё встало на свои места, спасибо!